# What's wrong with this c program? Debugging it suggests that the program is struck at while (sqroot != 0);

Tags: c, math, integer-arithmetic

[**Here's a screenshot of debugging process**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWhg3.png)
I am learning to program in C. I am trying to find if a number is a mirror image or not, But the program compiles error-free yet didn't give the desired result. Debugging the program shows that it struck at while (sqroot != 0);

```
    // Mirror number
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    int main() {
            int num, rev1, rev2, rem1, rem2, sqr, sqroot;
            printf("Enter a number\n");
            scanf("%d", & num);
            sqr = pow(num, 2);
            while (sqr != 0) {
                    rem1 = sqr % 10;
                    rev1 = rev1 * 10 + rem1;
                    sqr = sqr / 10;

            }
            sqroot = sqrt(rev1);

            while (sqroot != 0); {
                    rem2 = sqroot % 10;
                    rev2 = rev2 * 10 + rem2;
                    sqroot = sqroot / 10;
            }

            if (rev2 == num)
                    printf("number is mirror");
            else
                    printf("Not a mirror number");

            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You don't initialize `rev1` before accessing it.  Same for `rev2`.

Comment: If you put a print after `while (sqroot != 0); {` where you output the value of `sqroot` every time, what does the value do?

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons that solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: enable warnings in your compiler, you should get some ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`while (sqroot != 0); { ... }` is an infinite loop. because the `;` is considered as an empty instruction. An instruction (empty or not) just after an `if (condition)` or a `while (condition)` is considered to be the **only** instruction of the `if`, `while`, `for` scope.

It is the same than writting

```
while (sqroot != 0)
{
    ; /* Do nothing */
}
/* The scope below doesn't belong to the while */
{
    rem2 = sqroot % 10;
    rev2 = rev2 * 10 + rem2;
    sqroot = sqroot / 10;
}
```

Remove the `;` and this problem should be solved.

```
while (sqroot != 0) {
    rem2 = sqroot % 10;
    rev2 = rev2 * 10 + rem2;
    sqroot = sqroot / 10;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But the ouput is same for every input? any suggestions?

Comment: You have some variables not initialized as stated in some comments and answer

Answer (score 3):

Initialize to rev1=0 and rev2=0.Because without a initial value,rev1 and rev2 will contain  garbage values so that run time error will occur.

Comment: That solved my problem. Thank you!