# I am unable to execute this line of code , Pls help and rectify?

Tags: java

```
final int size = 10 ;   
    int [] crr = new int [size];
    crr [0] = -1 ;
    crr [1] = 2 ;
    crr [2] = 6 ;
    crr [3] = 9 ;
    
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    for (int i = 0 ; i < crr.length ; i++ );
    {
        System.out.println ("The next element");
         crr [i]= reader .nextInt ();
        System.out.println (crr[i]);
```

**After Execution Says this :**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
> problems:     I cannot be resolved to a variable  I cannot be resolved
> to a variable

If I put i in the crr position it shows as its a problem. Please I need some advice on this.

If not copy the code and see the issue.

Comment: You are closing your `for` loop block with a `;`. Therefore your loop is closed and also the scope of your loop variable `i` ends.

Comment: @maloomeister Why do you not consider that an answer?

Comment: I cannot "copy the code and see the issue" because you did not provide a [mre].

Comment: @Yunnosch you're right. Updated.

Comment: @Cid A comment like that should be replaced by a duplicate close-vote - if you really think that it is the same problem in a different language and mentioning it is helpful to OP...

Comment: @Yunnosch I think it's unfair to VTC dupe for something I've answered

Comment: @Cid That is noble thinking, but I disagree. Having written it is the best way of knowing about a duplicate answer. At least it is not any less fair than mentioning your answer the way you did in your comment.

Comment: You got a point. And well, I'm usually a duplicate-hunter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's wrong with this c program? Debugging it suggests that the program is struck at while (sqroot != 0);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52610522/whats-wrong-with-this-c-program-debugging-it-suggests-that-the-program-is-stru)

Comment: Ah nvm, the typo reason passed

Answer (score 3):

You are closing your `for` loop block with a `;`. Therefore your loop is closed and also the scope of your loop variable `i` ends.
The correct loop would look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < crr.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("The next element");
    crr[i] = reader.nextInt();
    System.out.println(crr[i]);
}
```

You should maybe look into the [Java Code Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) which also tell you more about how to format your code.
Also, if you ask any questions in the future, you should provide a [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank u soo much my mistake will be rectified